# NuGet Source Control Integration for VS 2015

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package-restore

With Visual Studio 2013 (NuGet 2.8) we have been using the following approach to disable source control integration for NuGet:

Add the following section to a nuget.config file that exists relative to the solution: SolutionDir\.nuget\nuget.config.

```
<solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
</solution>
```

However, after upgrading to Visual Studio 2015 (NuGet 3.0) this directive doesn't seem to work any more. New and upgraded packages are added to source control.

I have tried adding this configuration to the ...\Users\user.name\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config file but it doesn't change anything.

I wonder if there is a new way to specify this behaviour in NuGet 3.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a bug. It is reported on the [Nuget Github site](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/980) and should be fixed in a coming release.

From deepakaravindr (assignee):

> We will work on a fix. For the time being, there are 2 possible workarounds
>
> - First one is to move nuget.config from the solution folder .nuget to the solution level and directory
> - Second one is to undo the changes to the packages folder

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why I couldn't find it. I looked there first!

Comment: Moving to the root folder of the solution does NOT work it doesn't change anything.  So there is only one option is to remove the [Add] from your pending changes... Any ETA on when that will be fixed?